# Python Creating Person Class and loading function from txt.file

Tags: python-3.x, class, object

I am trying to configure code to define a class person and have a function that reads data from txt.file that will be used to create the objects. I am unable to change the arguments in the methods due to restrictions.

The purpose of the Person class is to represent a person who is linked to other people by social connections. Therefore each Person object must be able to store a set of references to other Person objects. (You will need to think about a suitable data type for storing a set of objects, and how you would need to initialize the empty set within the class definition.) In addition to storing the person’s friends, your Person class should also contain instance variables to keep track of the person’s name. If you wish to do so, you can extend this class by adding more methods.

A small snippet of the text file is 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE0BW.png)

```
Gill Bates: Jodee Killam, Natacha Osterhoudt, Jom Tones, Verdie Tong, Ossie Digangi

Jom Tones: Marry Blakely, Masako Miguel, Gill Bates

Joey Trammell: Jettie Wilham

Rozanne Schiavo: Mikki Yerby

Deena Massi: Milo Charlebois, Vicenta Seidel

Enrique Litz: Levi Strasser, Alton Justis

Sindy Worley: Vallie Taormina, Alysa Robichaux, Ossie Digangi

Yahaira Briones: Zoila Tarpey, Zandra Marsch

Tanesha Vanwinkle: Nestor Valentine, Shawana Mell, Jamar Mcclane
```

the Gill Bates and Jom Tones are unique objects and I need to ensure that they do not duplicate

the **load function** does the following:
1. Opens the file which contains the data set given.
2. Creates a new Person object for each record (line) in the file, which contains the name of the person
represented by that record.
3. Where a person’s record indicates that they have friends, you should use the addFriend() method to add
each friend to that Person object.3
4. Finally, return a list of all the Person objects that have been created from the file records (making sure to
have closed the file first).

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name):
        self.firs_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

    def add_friend(self, friend_person):
        self.friend_person = friend_person
# This method should add a new social connection to be stored in this Person object.
        pass # placeholder only. 

    def get_name(self):
        full_name = str(self.first_name)+" "+str(self.last_name)
        return(full_name)
        pass # placeholder only. 

    def get_friends(self):
        pass # placeholder only. 


def load_people():
    file = open("a2_sample_set.txt", "r")

    pass # placeholder only. To be implemented in task 1.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass # placeholder only. You may add your own testing code within this
         # main block to check if the code is working the way you expect.
```

I have tried to start but am having difficulties in going about this.

Comment: Find how to read a txt file. Depends on how the txt file is formatted, use some functions to transform it to a list, then for each Person, call Person.add_friend(friend). The hard part is transforming, since I don't know how your txt file looks like.

Comment: Thank you for viewing, my txt file is formatted as such as above ! Each line in the text file is one person and separated by semicolon are their friends

Comment: @AerysS has a good starting point.Couple of point about Friends: It appears from your data, a Person can have 0 or more Friends... are Friends an instance of Person? Is it possible two Persons can have the same friend?

Comment: I think the text file we need to store as person objects, so it is safe to assume that. For example in the text file the name before the semicolon will be stored first as an object

Answer (score 0):

Here I make the code to get all the names of each person's friends for you, assume that the txt file's format is exactly like that (a new line between each row).

```
file = open('names.txt', 'r')
listOfNames = []
for lines in file: // read txt file line by line
    if lines == '\n':
        continue
    else:
        listOfNames.append(lines.split(': '))
listOfFriends = [] // of each person
for eachlist in listOfNames:
    friendsOfEachPerson = eachlist[1].split(', ')
    friendsOfEachPerson[-1] = friendsOfEachPerson[-1].replace('\n', '')
    listOfFriends.append(friendsOfEachPerson)
print(listOfFriends)
```

You can create each Person object base on these names, and `add_friend` these Person to each other. If you want distinct names, manipulate both `listOfNames` and `listOfFriends` to get what you need. Hope it helps.

Comment: No problem. Also follow this guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers if you find my answer is satisfied.

Comment: how do we create person object base on these names ?

Comment: person1 = Person(firstname, lastname). It's basic OOP in Python.

Comment: for the method load_people() how can i split to store the Person name themselves i.e just lets say Gill Bates (before the semicolon) i can see that the listOfFriends prints the friends themselves without the Person

Comment: how would i also incorporate the OOP in the code would it be in a loop ? since i want to create instances of a person that are unique and the friends i add to the person are unique objects as well

Comment: Then remove this line `    if lines == '\n': continue else:`. You can loop for each name in the list.

Comment: Also like I said, manipulate the listOfNames and listOfFriends to get what you need.